# Is there a way to prevent Google Chrome from following an element that moves off the screen?

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, scroll

I have a page with a vertical carousel (adapted from [this one](https://codepen.io/mburnette/pen/giyHq)) that slides news `article`s up every couple of seconds. The problem is, when the top of the page intersects with this carousel, an `article` that moves upwards will force the page to slide up with it to remain in view. This happens only on Chrome (both mobile and desktop). Once you fully scroll past the carousel, this is no longer an issue.

Is it possible to prevent this behaviour? I would like the carousel to continue scrolling peacefully without dragging the page up if a tiny bit of it is still visible.

[Here is a codepen where the issue is visible](https://codepen.io/jac733/pen/bGdbggo). Open this in Chrome, scroll so that you can only see the lower half of the blue section, and wait for the carousel to update.

Thanks in advance for your time and for any help you might bring!